# Java calling Javascript function - Array distorted

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I am making js method call from a java program using javax.script.ScriptEngine.

In the js method I am building the following json with "f" key having an array value and I am return this following json I built...

```
{"s":0,"q":{"b":{"f":[{"r":{"cr":{"gte":"2012-04-01","lte":"2016-07-11","format":"yyyy-MM-dd"}}},{"t":{"x":"kl"}},{"t":{"e":"io"}}]}},"a":{"c":{"t":{"f":"x"}}}}
```

In java I see the same json with array distorted to with "0", "1" and "2" keys. Please look at the "f" value here...

```
{"s":0,"q":{"b":{"f":{"0":{"r":{"cr":{"gte":"2012-04-01","lte":"2016-07-11","format":"yyyy-MM-dd"}}},"1":{"t":{"x":"kl"}},"2":{"t":{"e":"io"}}}}},"a":{"c":{"t":{"f":"x"}}}}
```

here is the java code...

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
scriptEngine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("some.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Invocable inv = (Invocable) scriptEngine;
Object result = inv.invokeFunction("someFunc", "someparam");
```

Could you please gimme a hint as to why its getting distorted?

Here is the code that works showing my case...

**Javascript function - some.js**

```
function someFunc() {
    var result = {};
    result["q"] = "0";
    var f = [];
    f.push("a");
    f.push("b");
    f.push("c");
    result["f"] = f;
    print(JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
}
```

**Java Class**

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class SomeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        scriptEngine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("some.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        Invocable inv = (Invocable) scriptEngine;

        Object result = inv.invokeFunction("someFunc");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
JS log: {"q":"0","f":["a","b","c"]}
java log: {"q":"0","f":{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c"}}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just added MCVE code

Comment: Are you trying to produce a JSON string, or is that just for demonstration?

Comment: @shmosel Thank you very much. I got what you were inferring to and found the solution.